# MATLAB workspace not showing variables

Tags: matlab

I tried to import an excel file into my matlab program and tried to extract data from it:

```
clc;
clear all;
load lab3q2.mat
t = lab3q2(:,1);
v = lab3q2(:,2);
i = lab3q2(:,3);

plot(t,v)
hold on;
plot(t,i)
```

Everytime I run this script, I get command window output:

```
>> lab3q2

lab3q2 =

     0     0   -12
    10   325     0
    20   325    12
    30   325    12
    40     0    12
    50  -325     0
    60  -325   -12
    70  -325   -12
    80     0   -12
```

However, I do not get any plot. Surprisingly, the workspace **doesn't register the variables t,v,i.** This seemed to suggest that the script isnt running...but then if that were the case, I wouldn't have got command window output..

What exactly is going on? Why am I not getting any plot? Why isn't the workspace registering the variables t,v,i ?

Comment: It is because the variable `lab3q2` is overshadowing the script name, so if you type `lab3q2` you are going to output the contents of the variable, not run the script. Rename the script, and it will work.

Comment: Thats kind of what I suspected initially. It works.